# How to make the Word-open dialog visible and frontmost?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, window, powershell-5.0, dialog

When Word has following limitation with PDF

1. when not set as default App for PDF
2. does not show PDF it exported
3. cannot Open PDF navigated by Recent Items

I am using PowerShell Script to have Word open most recent PDF; I need help how to modify following script to bring Window (opened PDF) to the frontmost - as would be activated if alt-tabbed to the application.

```
    $latestPDF = Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory *.pdf | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$fullpath = Join-Path -Path $desktop_path -ChildPath $PDF
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("$latestPDF")
$word.Visible = $true
$hwnd = $doc.ActiveWindow.Hwnd
[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
```

Comment: PDF documents opened in Word will always be problematic for editing, even if they have been run through OCR or have the text components.